# Publishing Gradle snapshots locally

Tags: maven, gradle, publishing, snapshot

Here is my `dummy` project's `build.gradle` file:

```
apply plugin: 'groovy'

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.3.3'
    compile 'org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:1.7.7'

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.11'
    testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-all:1.10.8'
}

task sourcesJar(type: Jar, dependsOn: classes) {
    classifier = 'sources'
    from sourceSets.main.allSource
}

artifacts {
    archives sourcesJar
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '1.11'
}
```

When I run `gradle clean build -Pversion=1.2.3`, this packages up all my code and creates a `build/libs/dummy-1.2.3.jar` for me.

I would like to know the absolute *bare minimum* amount of Gradle code necessary so that I could publish my "dummy" JARs to my local Maven cache (`mavenLocal()`). Additionally, how does this work with versioning? I *could* always specify a concrete version for the dummy JAR, but when I'm publishing locally, it makes more sense (to me, at least) to publish `SNAPSHOT` versions. I *could* just run `gradle clean build -Pversion=0.1.SNAPSHOT`, but then my concern is whether or not other local projects would pick up the latest `SNAPSHOT` versions.

So again:

1. What's the bare minimum code to publish `dummy` locally?
2. Any way, when publishing locally, to specify a `SNAPSHOT` version that other projects always pick up the latest copy of?
3. What would other local projects need to use to pick up this `SNAPSHOT`? Something like `compile ':dummy:LATEST'`?

Comment: Has the question you asked been answered? If so accept the answer please.

Answer (score 9):

[Here](https://github.com/Opalo/stackoverflow/tree/master/27752776) I've prepared sample project for you, this is the bare minimum when it comes to `build.gradle` configuration.

1. You need to add `apply plugin: 'maven'` and set `group = 'somegroup'`. `maven` plugin gives `install` task and `group` is required to install artifact in maven repository.

   Then run `gradle clean install`. If no version passed, it will evaluate to *unspecified*, if no `artifactId` configured it will evaluate to `project.name`. [Here](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/maven_plugin.html) You can find how to configure other maven properties.

   Installing snapshot for local development is definitely a good idea.
2. If You'd like other project to always pick the latest version of SNAPSHOT You need to add the following piece of code to `build.gradle` scripts. It guarantees resolving to the latest version.

   ```
   configurations.all {
      resolutionStrategy {
        cacheChangingModulesFor 0, 'seconds'
      }
   }
   ```
3. First of all You need to add snapshot repo to `repositories` block (just a sample) - with local maven repo, this step is not needed:

   ```
   maven {
       url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots'
   }
   ```

   Dependency should be specified as:

   ```
   group:artifact:0.+
   ```

Feel free to ask in case of any questions.

Answer (score 2):

1) You just need to do a

```
gradle install
```

2) Specify whatever version you like - a SNAPSHOT version makes sense for active development. Once you think your library is less likely to change you should definitely go for a non-snapshot version.

3) You have to specify a dependency to the version you have in your local repo, just as for 3rd party libraries.

Comment: Which plugin is needed to perform that? I get this when I try:
```
Task 'install' not found in root project 'kotti'.
```